# Ubuntu 18.10 on Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ICH missing battery indicator/management

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, 18.10, ideapad

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on a fresh new Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ICH, and I have issues with the battery. The battery indicator does not appear in the status bar, and `acpi -V` shows:

```
Adapter 0: off-line
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 8: intel_powerclamp no state information available
Cooling 9: pch_cannonlake no state information available
Cooling 10: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 11: iwlwifi no state information available
```

(note that the adapter was plugged in when I ran this).

Here is `dmesg  | grep -i battery`:

`[    7.543690] battery: ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery absent)`

The battery is most certainly there (it's internal and non-removable). BIOS is configures as EFI, in non-secure boot mode, but I see nothing concerning power management.

There's a bunch of ACPI stuff at dmesg, which I will post if anyone deems them useful. I see people mentioning a bunch of other issues but not this, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

Edit: I really need to bump this. Noone really has the same problem, or any idea?

Edit: someone suggested: I have the same problem with same model (version with 8750h and GTX 1050). Last thing that I not tried was bios upgrade. Some problems (like no wifi) were resolved with adding to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf new line "blacklist ideapad-laptop". Problems with battery indicator was gone with yesterday's update to Disco Dingo (19.04).
I confirm that I do see the battery indicator on 19.04, though a bunch of other unrelated issues popped up. The indicator still shows the charging icon when unplugged, though.

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to solve the problem?
I am experiencing the same fault, with the additional problem of some of function keys (ie. screen brightness controls and other) not working.
I was hoping perhaps you were able to find some solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to get anywhere with this. The issues with the hotkeys affect me as well. The volume ones work as well as the F9 one (lock), everything else doesn't. THe hotkeys are no big issue since you can access the same function elsewhere, but the "invisible" battery means you never know the charge state, and, I suspect, no powersave mechanism ever kicks in. I am not hoping for the next Ubuntu release to magically solve this, but I hold little hope, since I tried installing more recent kernels via ukuu, and none solved it (moreover, they caused issues with the nvidia drivers).

Comment: Same problem here. Another user on the Lenovo forums with an Ideapad 330-15ICH 81FK00GCRU mentioned he was able to solve the issue by using Ubuntu 16.4 ([link](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx/Ubuntu-18-10-on-Lenovo-Ideapad-330-15ICH/td-p/4396303)). Apparently that solves other issues too (wifi, trackpad...) I can't confirm yet whether that's true. I'll try with a LiveUSB when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem is caused by kernels between 4.16 and 4.19. ubuntu 16.04.6 works (kernel 4.15), and so does Ubuntu 18.04, but only if you install from 18.04.0 or 18.04.1 (their kernel is also 4.15), but neither Ubuntu 18.04.2 nor Ubuntu 18.10 work (kernel 4.18). These problems have been fixed in kernel 5.0. Solutions:

1. Either you use versions with kernel 4.15 (Ubuntu 16.04.6 / 18.04). This kernel has some small issues with the touchpad, though.
2. Or you install Ubuntu 18.04 and, afterwards, enable the LTSEnablementStack

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

linux-generic-hwe-18.04-**edge** is necessary if you want to install kernel 5.0

Don't forget to enable the NVIDIA drivers in 'Software & Updates' -> 'Additional Drivers'